# Error log - database schema?

Tags: mysql, error-handling, social-networking

I am creating a user content website like linkedin.com and wondering for error handling (al the backend blowups) + any front end user issues like invalid links, etc do i need to log them into a table or does the server / database auto record these?

If i need to create a schema what info do i need to track outside of the basic bug status, type, user_id, create datetime etc? And if my database goes down then how will i log all these? Being a user site i expect a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0):

A database is probably the last place to put the logs. By all means load the data in there for analysis but for logging you want as sraightforward and simple a system as possible.

NB that does NOT mean opening/closing files and writing to them!

Anything you write to the stderr stream should appear in your webserver error log. Alternatively (preferably?) configure PHP to [log errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) using the OS logging functionality and use 'trigger_error' to record events which do not intrisically throw an error.

Comment: But log them to where? I assume a text file? Do i have to clean the file up if the size grows as text fiels have a size limit i assume?

Comment: Use the OS logging facility - I don't know what OS you run on - you did not say - therefore I don't know how logging is implmented / configured on your machine.